# Remove NFS mounted partitions from Icinga2 output?

Tags: linux, monitoring, partition, icinga2

We have about 10 servers which an NFS partition is mounted on all of them. All hosts on Icinga displays that NFS partition, so when NFS partition threshold is reached 10 mail notifications are sent for that specific error.

**The question** is how can I remove NFS partition from different hosts.

For now default config is as below:

```
apply Service for (display_name => config in host.vars.snmp.disks) {
    import "generic-service-faxir"

    check_command = "snmp-storage-parameteric"
    vars += config

    if (vars.snmp_warn == ""){
        vars.snmp_warn = "70"
    }
    if (vars.snmp_crit == ""){
        vars.snmp_crit = "85"
    }

    //Converting capacity to percentage
    if(vars.capacity != ""){
        if(vars.capacity_warn != ""){
            vars.snmp_warn = 100 * vars.capacity_warn / vars.capacity
        }
        if(vars.capacity_crit != ""){
            vars.snmp_crit = 100 * vars.capacity_crit / vars.capacity
        }
    }

    //ext2, ext3, and ext4 has 5% reserved for OS
    if (host.vars.os == "Linux"){
         vars.snmp_storage_reserved = 5
    }

   ignore where host.vars.os !in ["Linux", "Windows"]
}
```

**EDIT1:**
the command code is as below:

```
/**
 * based on:
 * snmp storage - Disk/Memory
 *   Url reference: http://nagios.manubulon.com/snmp_storage.html
 */
object CheckCommand "snmp-storage-parameteric" {
    import "snmp-manubulon-command"

    command = [ ManubulonPluginDir + "/check_snmp_storage.pl" ]

    arguments += {
        "-m" = "$snmp_storage_name$"
        "-f" = {
            set_if = "$snmp_perf$"
        }
        "-R" = "$snmp_storage_reserved$"
        "-T" = "$snmp_storage_type$"
        "-G" = ""
     }

    vars.snmp_storage_name = "^/$$"
    vars.snmp_storage_type = "pu"
    vars.snmp_warn = 80
    vars.snmp_crit = 90
    vars.snmp_perf = true
    vars.snmp_storage_reserved=0
}
```

Comment: It is unclear without knowledge about the checkcommand and used plugin.

Comment: @dnsmichi please take a look at the edit part.

Comment: Ah, okay. Keep in mind - all attributes will still require the underlaying plugin to support it. Add such information to future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but you could look into the following command parameters:

- match a name pattern - https://github.com/dnsmichi/manubulon-snmp/blob/master/plugins/check_snmp_storage.pl#L164

  `-m, --name=NAME
  Name in description OID (can be mounpoints '/home' or 'Swap Space'...)
  This is treated as a regexp : -m /var will match /var , /var/log, /opt/var ...
  Test it before, because there are known bugs (ex : trailling /)
  No trailing slash for mountpoints !`
- exclude specific volumes - https://github.com/dnsmichi/manubulon-snmp/blob/master/plugins/check_snmp_storage.pl#L180

  `-e, --exclude
  Select all storages except the one(s) selected by -m
  No action on storage type selection`
- select a storage type - https://github.com/dnsmichi/manubulon-snmp/blob/master/plugins/check_snmp_storage.pl#L169

  `"-q, --storagetype=[Other|Ram|VirtualMemory|FixedDisk|RemovableDisk|FloppyDisk
                  CompactDisk|RamDisk|FlashMemory|NetworkDisk]`

Best is to test the various parameters on the command line and then add them to your CheckCommand and Service definition.